# How to embed a mxml code in a JSP/Servlet/html file?

Tags: java, apache-flex, jsp, servlets, mxml

I want a way to embed the mxml code into a jsp or servlet or a html file. How can we do that? would i have to embed the mxml code or the compiled swf/html file from that mxml code?

Comment: Include the code you've tried in your post. However you can use `<jsp:include>` action.

Comment: now for example i've made a file abc.mxml, would i use the abc.html file to be included or abc.swf? I am asking this question in the perspective of creating a flex + java integrated project using flash builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is how to create Java / Flex applications in a Model View Controller architecture.

1. MXML - View, shows the user interface of the application
2. ActionScript Classes - Controller, extracting & processing information from XML or JSON file returned by Java layer (Java Servlet / JSP).
   Compile MXML & ActionScript to a SWF file and embed it within the dynamic HTML generated by Java Servlet / JSP.
3. Java Servlet/ JSPs - Model contains code for fetching data and converting it to XML / JSON format.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You have to serve the SWF file as a any static file. Serving the MXML file would be of no use unless you want to show your code.

Of course you can copy or point to the HTML code generated by Flash Builder, because it contains the code to actually include the SWF in the page.